# multi class Youden index

Tags: r, classification, multinomial

I am interested in optimising predictions for a multinomial regression model with 3 (or more) classes according to various measures.

For two-class models (logistic regression), this can be done in the pROC package using the coords function with `best.method="youden"` or `closest.topleft`.  This will choose the threshold on the probability of success as predicted by the logistic regression model that either maximises specificity+sensitivity (youden) or gives the point in the ROC curve closest in the Euclidean distance to the point `(1,1)` (`closest.topleft`).

In the three (ore more) class case, it is possible to generalise sensitivity+specificity to the sum over classes of sensitivity for each class.  We can then ask, if we choose a vector of weights on the probabilities of the non-reference classes, which vector of weights will maximise this quantity?  This set of weights will give the analogue in the three (or more) class case of the Youden index.

My questions are:

1. is there an R package and command that implement this?  If not, I will write one, but I want to make sure I am not duplicating work that has already been done.
2. If not, what other functionalities would be useful to build into this package?  For example, it would be possible to find the best set of weights that ensure one of the sensitivities is at least above some set threshold.  It would also be possible to find the analogue of `closest.topleft`--the set of weights that give sensitivities closest to `(1,1,1)`, and so on.  Also, it would be possible to include some plotting capabilities, e.g., for the 3-class situation, a 3D version of an ROC curve that plots the three sensitivities on three axes.

Thanks!